# How to delete doubled weather widget in El Capitan?

Tags: notifications, macos

After upgrading to OS X 10.11 I have two weather widgets (one, maybe, is inactive). So, is it possible to delete the blank one? If yes, where or how I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 simple steps to solve the problem (works even in OS X 10.11.1):

1. Go to `/private/var/db/locationd/` from your finder or terminal;
2. Give you full privilege to change files inside this folder;
3. Convert `clients.plist` file from binary mode into xml1 by running this command in your terminal: `sudo plutil -convert xml1 /private/var/db/locationd/clients.plist`;
4. Open the clients.plist and remove the key and dictionary pair in the configuration file. For my case I delete all fields that includes `weather` word;
5. Don’t forget to convert back the `client.plist` into binary file using the command below in Terminal: `sudo plutil -convert binary1 /private/var/db/locationd/clients.plist`
6. The prelast step is to restart the daemon that monitor the change of location. Type this command in Terminal: `sudo killall -KILL locations`;
7. Finally `com.apple.ncplugin.weather`disappeared from Location Services, I reaccepted to check my weather by location and everything starting to work perfectly.

[This](http://sayzlim.net/remove-items-applications-services-mountain-lion/) article helps me.

Answer (score -1):

To delete a doubled or unwanted widget in El Capitan open dashboard, press the option key,click on the widget you want to remove and a little X will appear.  Click on the X and Voila!  It's gone!

Comment: It's not located in Dashboard, it's settings property.